# Read in and format a text file with python 2.x

Tags: python

If I have data in a text file that looks like:

```
# this is a header
# and so is this
#
alligator 27.2 83.4
bear 23.9 90.2
cat 12.56 0.98
dog 15.97 0.88884
...
...
```

...I know I can read that data in (make a list of lists corresponding to the lines of data) by using the following block of code:

```
file1 = 'tmp.txt'

file1_data = []
data_input = open(file1,'r')
for line in data_input:
    if "#" not in line:
        line = line.strip().split()
        first_col_datum = line[0]
        second_col_datum = float(line[1])
        third_col_datum = float(line[2])
        file1_data.append([first_col_datum,second_col_datum,third_col_datum])
data_input.close()
```

...but my intuition tells me there is a much much more elegant way to complete this task. Basically I would like to read in the file line by line, ignore '#'s, and supply the command with a 'format' for each element in the line (like ["%s","%0.6f","%0.6f","%0.6f","%i"] or something...I will always know this a priori). What is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write in the middle of the file use

`fileinput module`.

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\new.txt",inplace=True):
    if not re.match(r"^#.*$",line):
        #do the formatting
        print "something", #print("something", end ="") for python 3
```

Done in a few lines

remember whatever you print that will go in the file.So you have to read and print every line and modify whichever you want to replace.Also use `print "asd",`  the `,` at the end is important as It will prevent `print` from putting a newline there.

Now you dont watch `lines starting with`#`.

So add the condition.

```
if not re.match(r"^#.*$",line):
    #do the formatting and print
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file1_data = []
with open(file1) as data_input: # with automatically closes your files
    # skip headers 
    next(data_input), next(data_input), next(data_input)
    for line in data_input:
        # unpack 
        first_col_datum, second_col_datum, third_col_datum = line.split()
        file1_data.append([first_col_datum,float(second_col_datum), float(third_col_datum)])
```

Output:

```
[['alligator', 27.2, 83.4], ['bear', 23.9, 90.2], ['cat', 12.56, 0.98], ['dog', 15.97, 0.88884]]
```

Or use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to skip the headers:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(file1) as data_input:
    for line in islice(data_input,3,None):
        first_col_datum, second_col_datum, third_col_datum = line.split()
        file1_data.append([first_col_datum,float(second_col_datum),float(third_col_datum)])

print(file1_data)
[['alligator', 27.2, 83.4], ['bear', 23.9, 90.2], ['cat', 12.56, 0.98], ['dog', 15.97, 0.88884]]
```

Not sure I fully understand the formatting part or what you want to do with it but if you want to format use str.format:

```
([first_col_datum, "{:6f}".format(float(second_col_datum)),"{:6f}".format(float(third_col_datum))])
```

If you were trying to ignore lines starting with `#` using an if statement you should use `str.startswith`:

```
if not line.startswith("#")
```

Not sure where in your question it says you want to write the data to a file but if you do:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(file1) as data_input, open("output.txt","w") as out:
    for line in islice(data_input,3,None):
        first_col_datum, second_col_datum, third_col_datum = line.split()
        out.write("{} {:6f} {:6f}\n".format(first_col_datum,float(second_col_datum), float(third_col_datum)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method by which we can do this is through lambda in list comprehension or lambda with map function

```
desired_list = lambda str_list: [str_list[0], float(str_list[1]), float(str_list[2])]
# With list comprehension
with open(file1) as fo:
    output_list = [desired_list(content.strip().split(" ", 3) for content in fo.read().split("\n") if content and '#' not in content]

# With filter and map function
output_list = []
with open(file1) as fo:
    fitered_list = filter(lambda x: if x and '#' not in x, fo.read().split("\n"))
    output_list = map(desired_list, filtered_list)
```

I would prefer putting the logic into a function and calling it rather than using lambda, much like Padraic Cunningham.

```
def desired_list(line):
    if not line.strip() and '#' in line.strip():
        return None
    line_list = line.split(" ", 3)
    return [line_list[0], float(line_list[1]), float(line_list[2])]

with open(file1) as fo:
    file_contents = fo.read().split("\n")
    output_list = filter(None, map(desired_list, file_contents))
```

This gives control over the logic pretty much than the other two methods.